# I do not see my testnet transactions and Ether

Tags: testnets, metamask, faucets

I installed MetaMask, connected to Ropsten TestNet, clicked "Buy", then clicked "[Ropsten Test Faucet](https://faucet.metamask.io/)".  There, I clicked "request 1 ether from facuet", waited several seconds, and saw a transaction id "0xb3840f20b3c9b781347edf7e0d1b633fb60fa8a5a4808032db224e9deb33ae9a". 
But, clicking the link brought me to [this page](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb3840f20b3c9b781347edf7e0d1b633fb60fa8a5a4808032db224e9deb33ae9a) which says "Unable to locate Transaction entry". Indeed, even after waiting several hours and clicking several more times, my balance (as I see in MetaMask) is still 0.

I tried [another faucet](http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/) but it did not help - my balance in Ropsten TestNet is still 0 and [I see no transactions](http://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x76bd5929f700e3658b5c465070312b07a6d0050e). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be constructive, are you able to use Kovan testnet for the meantime?  There might be some Ropsten testnet instability currently.

Comment: @eth yes, I can use Kovan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eth commenter is correct. There have been some new attacks on Ropsten, please be patient or use another test net for now.

Testrpc is great, too!